# How to Automatic Reply to Sender if email contains certain words?

Tags: gmail, automation, gmail-canned-response

We have G Suite (Gmail) email, and we have the same question every day. We thought about Automatic Replies to emails that came with certain words.

We are looking for an (even paid) service (which is not Outlook) that will check if an email (subject+body) contains certain words and will be auto replied with a specific email to those words.

For example: a mail having the words "world" and "cup", will be sent an auto reply email with "Welcome to  the football team" in the subject. 
Or for example: If you send "Package" and "Delivered", the sender will receive a "Thank you" email.

I've checked Freshdesk and automate.io but they didn't really meet our expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using a combination of `Filters` and `Templates`** (they used to be called `Canned responses`) you can achieve what you asked for.

Please follow these steps:

1. Go to `Settings` > `Advanced`
2. Enable `Templates`
3. Create a draft email to your liking **leaving `Recipients` blank**
4. Go to the bottom of your newly created draft email and click on the kebab menu (3 little dots/`More options`)
5. Select `Templates` > `Save draft as template` > `Save as new template` (done here)
6. Now go back to `Settings` > `Filters and blocked addresses`
7. Create a filter to your liking (first screen) and click on `Continue`
8. Check the `Send template:` and choose your template
9. Save
10. Enjoy :)

Repeat the above steps (3 to 9) for as many templates as you like.

> ***Note:*** *The option `Send template:` will **not** appear until you enable `Templates` in step 2.*