# G Suite selective email migration from Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-workspace-for-business

I am interested in **partially migrating emails from my personal google account to my new G Suite account**. I want to migrate all emails containing a certain label and no others.
I know there is an option to exclude certain labels, but I couldn't find a way to exclude all but one. The labeled emails are also labeled with the "inbox" label.

Background:
Up until today our company used a server based mail client which I imported into my personal google client via POP3. I now want to migrate only these emails to our new G Suite account without all of my personal emails.
I have full super-admin access.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect these two accounts via IMAP.
You could use Thunderbird which is easy to manage.

You can find more details in [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67813).

---

#### ***Pro Tip***:

As for **future emails** (which may still be coming to your personal email), just **create a filter and have them forwarded** to the new address. Using the same filter and a **template** ([as describede  in this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/137143/how-to-automatic-reply-to-sender-if-email-contains-certain-words)) you can let the sender know of the new address.